# Obtaining distinct values from viewbag list to use as optgroup for multiselect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, entity-framework

In my controller, I define:

```
        private List<Store> GetStoreZoneList()
    {
        List<Store> stores = Store.GetList();
        stores = stores.OrderBy(b => b.Id).ToList();

        return stores;
    }
```

Which I then pass to my view using viewbag:

```
this.ViewBag.StoreZoneList = this.GetStoreZoneList();
```

In my view, I'm trying to create a multiselect drop down grouped by ZoneId.  The Store entity is a list of stores with their zones.  I want to display the list of stores, but grouped by the zone.

```
<select>
@foreach (var group in this.ViewBag.StoreZoneList.Select(new {group:ZoneId}).Distinct())
{
    <optgroup label="@group">
    @foreach (var store in this.VewiBag.StoreZoneList.Where(r => r.ZoneId == group))
    {
        <option value="@Id">@Name</option>   
    }
    </optgroup>
}
```

I'm receiving an error "The name 'group' does not exist in the current context" and "The name 'ZoneId' does not exist in the current context".  How do I get the list of values for optgroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going back to my original structure.  I added a List for Zones in the controller:

```
        private List<Zone> GetZoneList()
    {
        List<Zone> zones = Zone.GetList();
        zones = zones.OrderBy(b => b.Id).ToList();

        return zones;
    }
```

put that in a viewbag, and then used it for the optgroup in my view:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="ZoneAutho" class="multiselect">
@foreach (var group in this.ViewBag.ZoneList)
{
    <optgroup label="Zone @group.Id">
    @foreach (var store in this.ViewBag.StoreZoneList)
    {
        if (store.ZoneId == group.Id) 
        {
            <option value="@store.Id"> @store.Id - @store.Name</option>   
        }
    }
    </optgroup>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the purpose is of the distinct call is.  Is it to not have any duplicate groups?  The group by should take care of that.

Also, should it be @Name there in the second loop?  I think you're trying to do the following:

```
var groups = (from c in this.ViewBag.StoreZoneList
              group c by c.ZoneId into d
              select new
              {
                   GroupId = d.ZoneId
              });
<select>
@foreach (var group in groups)
{
    <optgroup label="@group.GroupId">
    @foreach (var store in this.ViewBag.StoreZoneList.Where(r => r.ZoneId == group.GroupId))
    {
        <option value="@Id">@store.Name</option>   
    }
    </optgroup>
}
</select>
```

You can do this much more simply by grouping it in your view model or controller and binding to a select list.  Like so:

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private List<Group> GetStoreZoneList()
{
    List<Store> stores = Store.GetList();
    stores = stores.OrderBy(b => b.Id).ToList();

    return (from c in stores
            group c by c.ZoneId into d
            select new Group()
            {
                GroupId = d.ZoneId,
                Name = c.Name
            });;
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ZoneId", new SelectList(this.ViewBag.StoreZoneList, "GroupId", "Name"))
```

Comment: I used your second suggestion.  In the GetStoreZoneList() definition, I had some errors using your code.  I've modified it, and reduced the errors, but now I still get "the name 'c' does not exist in the current context"   Here's the part I changed:             return (from c in stores
                    group c by new { c.ZoneId } into d
                    select new
                    {
                        GroupId = d.Key.ZoneId,
                        Name = c.Name
                    });